# ThinkPad X230 X230T X220 X220T reach over 100% volume with keyboard shortcut in GNOME?

Tags: audio, gnome, shortcuts, thinkpad, ubuntu-14.04

My ThinkPad speakers aren't that loud and gnome on ubuntu 14.04 doesn't let me go over 100% volume using volume keys. I can go over 100 percent by going to settings > sound. is there any way go over 100% with keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

This instruction is for GNOME 3 on Ubuntu 14.04 for ThinkPad X220/230 (Tablet) and might work on other systems and distributions

Go to all settings > keyboard > shortcuts > custom shortcuts

click +

Name: VolPlus10P
Command: pactl set-sink-volume 0 +10%

Click Apply

click Disable in front of the VolPlus10P
then hold Ctrl and press the dedicated volume increase button

in future if you hold Ctrl and press the dedicated volume increase button it will cause the volume to go 10% up and you can go over the 100% limit

click +

Name: VolSet150P
Command: pactl set-sink-volume 0 150%

Click Apply

click Disable in front of the VolSet150P
then hold Windows Key and press the dedicated volume increase button

in future if you hold Windows Key and press the dedicated volume increase button it will cause the volume to go 150%

click +

Name: VolSet100P
Command: pactl set-sink-volume 0 100%

Click Apply

click Disable in front of the VolSet100P
then hold Windows Key and press the dedicated volume decrease button

in future if you hold Windows Key and press the dedicated volume decrease button it will cause the volume to go 100%